# UIWebView in full screen hides status bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uistatusbar

I am opening video in UIWebView with following code.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Navigatin Type %d %@",navigationType, request);
    if (navigationType == 0) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarBtn;
        [self showVideoInWebView:[request.URL absoluteString]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)showVideoInWebView:(NSString *)urlStr
{
    [mainWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]]];
}
```

but when my mainWebView opens in full screen it hides my status bar.

I don't want to hide status bar

then how can I show my status bar?

Comment: rest of the app shows status bar and only one controller is hiding it?

Comment: @samfisher:Yes,exactly right. Only this controller hides status bar.

Comment: you need to check if there is any LOC in this controller where you have explicitly set statusbar as hidden `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` and set it to `setStatusBarHidden:NO` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can set Notification For making Status bar Visible.
Set The Notification for FullScreen Entry And Exit Notification ,SO that you could SHow And Hide The Status bar As Needed.

```
// For FullSCreen Entry 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoFullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

// For FullSCreen Exit
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoExitFullScreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];


- (void)videoFullScreen:(id)sender
   {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

   }

- (void)videoExitFullScreen:(id)sender
 {
  //Here do WHat You want
 }
```

I am Sure It'll be helpful to you.

Comment: that looks good but it uses undocumented behaviour and could break at some point

Comment: @Daij-Djan Yeah you are right.But I have used the same Code avoiding the same problem .Now My application uses the same Code is on AppStore...without any rejection

Comment: yes, Im saying: it IS a cool&reasonable way but in THEORY unsafe. Just ushering a word of warning :D

Answer (score 0):

that is the behaviour of the built-in movie player AFAIK you cant change it ... maybe with an alternative HTML5 control.

Comment: thanx for reply friend but then what is the solution? because this problem affects my other viewcontroller

Comment: no cocoa way .. dont know enough html to tell you more or IF that event works - sorry

Comment: one idea would be to keep the webview from playing movies (you could return NO from shouldStartLoading) THEN play it in your own view controller

Answer (score 0):

when your `UIWebView` begin Fullscreen at that time write this line..

just try with this line..

```
-(void)moviePlayerEvent:(NSNotification*)aNotification{

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
     NSLog(@"%i", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden);

}
```

Comment: ya i think here problem is vedioplayr in webview so refer html5 for vedio playing

Comment: @iPhone hey try my edited answer and also check this link.. http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44642

Answer (score 0):

Another Way:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                             
selector:@selector(VideoFullScreenExit:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:self.view.window];

- (void)VideoFullScreenExit:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```